# Sencha touch, JSONP is not loading on Mobile Device

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp

I'm developing Hybrid App with Sencha Touch + Phonegap. My tool is Sencha Architect 3.

I have following problems

- The program requests the data to the remote server by JSONP.
- The program well works on web browser (chrom).
- The program's most functions perfectly work on the Android Emulator and Mobile Device (Galaxy S3).
- But Data loading by JSONP is not working at all.

I tried checking the log on the remote server (tail -f), but any request didn't reach at the serer. In the case of web browser, it works.

What's the problem? How do I resolve this problem?

ps. I used the eclipse when made a apk file. And I added the permission of USE INTERNET.

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I forgot to add the phonegap config file, config.xml in /res/ directory. And I modified the config file as adding the permission to access the internet.